Exercise 1.2.1 in Sturmfels' Algorithms in Invariant Theory: Minimally Nonstandard Monomials
First some standard terminology.
Fix some monomial order $\prec$ and let $I$ be an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.
Then the initial ideal $\operatorname{init}(I)$ of $I$ is the ideal generated by the initial monomials with respect to $\prec$ of polynomials in $I$.
Monomials in $\operatorname{init}(I)$ are known as nonstandard and monomials not in $\operatorname{init}(I)$ are known as standard. Here is the question at hand:
$\textbf{Exercise 1.2.1}$ Let $\prec$ be a monomial order and let $I$ be an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.
A monomial $m$ is minimally nonstandard if $m$ is nonstandard and all proper divisors of $m$ are standard.
Show that the set of minimally nonstandard monomials is finite.
My only idea is that $\operatorname{init}(I)$ is a monomial ideal, and monomial ideals are finitely generated by monomials.
However, I am not sure how to argue that this list of generators must necessarily contain the minimally nonstandard monomials.

For context, see also this question.

I don't think the question I asked there has much to do with the question I asked in this post. If there's a connection to be made there then I'd love to know, maybe it'll help me solve this one.

Let $M$ be any set of monomial generators for $\operatorname{init}(I)$, and let $m$ be any minimally nonstandard monomial.
Since $m$ is a monomial and it belongs to the monomial ideal $\operatorname{init}(I)$, we have $m' \mid m$ for some monomial $m' \in M$.
Since $m$ is minimally nonstandard and $m'$ is nonstandard, $m'$ cannot be a proper divisor of $m$, so $m = m'$.
So any set of monomial generators for $\operatorname{init}(I)$ contains all the minimally nonstandard monomials.
Finally, we know from Dickson's lemma that there exists a finite set $M$ of monomial generators for $\operatorname{init}(I)$, and the claim follows.

Beautiful. Thanks so much. Glad to see my intuition of minimally nonstandard monomials being in the set of generators was at least on the right track.
